# How to simulate a request in JUNIT (spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I'm trying to emulate a request behaviours in one of my junit test.
Basically, I have a bean with scope="request".
In my Junit, I want to be able to simulate a request, then close it and open a new one to check that my bean is working fine.
Example:

```
openRequest();
modifyMyBean();
closeRequest();
openRequest();
checkThatMyBeanIsNew();
```

I've about simpleThreadScope, but I can't figure out how to close an open request.
I tried to run modifyMyBean() and checkThatMyBeanIsNew() in 2 separate threads but it didn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but an appropriate in my opinion. Since 3.2 version, spring-mvc bundled a set of test utility classes for unit testing that provides a comprehensive set of mock objects for Servlet API and Spring MVC objects. The link to [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) and these [blog series](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-mvc-test-tutorial/) should give you enough details